# Why second call of getValue() from HashMap returns null?

Tags: java, hashmap

I met strange behavior. I have map in map. During second map iteration I call getValue() twice. First time values are returned correctly but after second call getValue() always returns null, why?

```
Map<Integer, Map<Integer, String>> metricsColors = new HashMap<Integer, Map<Integer, String>>();
for (Entry<Affiliate, Map<Field, ApValue>> rowEntry : apValues.entrySet()) {
    Map<Integer, String> metricColor = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    String finalMetricColor = null;
    for (Entry<Field, ApValue> fieldValueEntry : rowEntry.getValue().entrySet()) {
        if (fieldValueEntry.getKey().getType() == FieldType.CLASSIFICATION) {
            metricColor.put(
                fieldValueEntry.getKey().getMetrics().getId(),
                fieldValueEntry.getValue().getValue()
            ); // HERE IS CORRECT.
            if (fieldValueEntry.getKey().getForFinalClassification() != null && fieldValueEntry.getKey().getForFinalClassification() == true) {
                finalMetricColor = fieldValueEntry.getValue().getValue(); // HERE IS A PROBLEM. Returns null always.
            }
        }
    }
    metricColor.put(2, finalMetricColor);
    metricsColors.put(rowEntry.getKey().getId(), metricColor);
}
```

For clarification I have 3 types of objects in this maps: Affiliate, Field and ApValue. All have equals and hashCode methods implemented.

Problem is in call this line:

`finalMetricColor = fieldValueEntry.getValue().getValue();`

It always returns null but the same call used few lines earlier works fine, why?

Comment: fieldValueEntry.getApValue() should not compile, there is no such method in Map.Entry

Comment: yes you're right it, there is no getApValue() but getValue() of course. It was my mistake during code refactoring only for this example. Now code should be correct and compiled.

Comment: I think this cannot happen, you are not modifying the fieldValueEntry entry, so how could the value by null in one case and non-null in this other? Are you sure about this behavior? Are you getting a NullPointerException when calling getValue() on fieldValueEntry.getValue() or is fieldValueEntry.getValue().getValue() returing null. In this case, the problem may be in the ApValue.getValue() method. Does it have the side-effect of nullifying its value?

Comment: @avidD: I suggest you rewrite this comment as an answer... :)

Comment: `fieldValueEntry.getValue()` has type `ApValue`.  Show us the implementation of `ApValue.getValue()`.  Have you confirmed that the call to `metricColor.put()` which you claim "works fine" is not just putting a null value into that map?

Comment: Are you sure your if test works? You said you are saying that it returns null because your debugguer don't stop twice with the conditional break. But maybe the line is not executed at all.

Comment: @avidD: thanks for your suggestion. Your answer cause I finally started thinking in different way and noticed what was the real problem. The problem wasn't getValue() but implementation of getForFinalClassification() - I believed it should work as expected but wasn't. Anyway thanks for a clue but I cannot set you comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you are :-)

I think this cannot happen, you are not modifying the fieldValueEntry entry, so how could the value by null in one case and non-null in this other? Are you sure about this behavior? Are you getting a NullPointerException when calling getValue() on fieldValueEntry.getValue() or is fieldValueEntry.getValue().getValue() returing null. In this case, the problem may be in the ApValue.getValue() method. Does it have the side-effect of nullifying its value?

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `fieldValueEntry.getValue().getValue()` rather than `fieldValueEntry.getApValue().getValue()`

Comment: As far as I know getApValue() is not a method of Map.Entry.

Comment: oops, I meant the other way around... Like @Bhesh Gurung says how does it even compile?

Comment: sorry for inconvenience, it was typo, i've changed getApValue() to getValue() what should be of course.

Answer (score -1):

Either start the debugger or put logging statements in the code to find out.  But before you do that, split the statements to see things more clearly.  Similar to this (SLF4J logging syntax):

```
for (...)
    for (...)
        if (...)

            log.debug("fieldValueEntry: {}", fieldValueEntry);

            ApValue apValue1 = fieldValueEntry.getValue();
            log.debug("apValue1: {}", apValue1);

            String value1 = apValue1.getValue(); // HERE IS CORRECT.
            log.debug("value1: {}", value1);

            metricColor.put(fieldValueEntry.getKey().getMetrics().getId(), value1);

            if (fieldValueEntry.getKey().getForFinalClassification() != null && fieldValueEntry.getKey().getForFinalClassification() == true) {

                ApValue apValue2 = fieldValueEntry.getValue();
                log.debug("apValue2: {}", apValue2);

                String value2 = apValue2.getValue(); // HERE IS A PROBLEM. Returns null always.
                log.debug("value2: {}", value2);

                finalMetricColor = value2; 
            }
```

Of course you can reuse the first variables in the 2nd case but you will want to know why you're seeing this behaviour.